# gtk_label_set_text() not working properly

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I am making a GUI using Glade and writing its code using GTK. I making a GUI so that if Start button is clicked, values of different parameters started showing in Gtk Label. I have made functions for all the parameter and I am calling each function in Start Button handler. I have added the this line gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(label),value) in one of the parameter. When I am running the code it is giving me error: Segmentation Fault(Core dumped).

So my first question is why it is giving me this error.?
I have made some research and I found something, so I added '&' with my value and then it was not giving me segmentation error but was displaying something else. Now how to fix this.?
Below is the code:

```
x = receivebuffer[4];
y = receivebuffer[3];
z = receivebuffer[2];



F = (x<<16) | (y<<8) | z;
printf("Value of F is %d\n", F);
gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(Voltage_Entry_Label), &F);
```

receivebuffer is the buffer in which I am receiving the data which has to be displayed on label. Only 4th,3rd and 2nd elements are useful so I have stored them in another variable and I have done some sort of simple logic and finally I am getting data in F. Printf() gives output like 104 but Gtk Label gives output like T. Now F has to be displayed in Gtk Label.

Concluding: why I have to use & to remove segmentation fault. why it is giving me something else on Gtk Label.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From gtk documentation, gtk_label_set_text should be used as :

```
void    gtk_label_set_text(GtkLabel *label, const gchar *str);
```

Here, second argument is a pointer. That is why you are getting a segmentation fault, when you pass second argument as int.
When you pass second argument as &F, it automatically convert (int *) to (const gchar *) and give the character represented by ASCII 104.

So the proper way is to use a temporary char array.

```
char temp[5];
sprintf(temp, "%d", F);
gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(Voltage_Entry_Label), temp);
```